# HTML tag parsing script

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I've written an HTML tag parsing script that I think should work but I'm getting a file not found error.  Maybe I'm having a senior moment but I'm stuck.  I have all of the *.html files that I want to parse in a directory called `Test` and I am executing the perl script from a folder called `temp` that has the directory Test in it.  The exact error is: *Error opening Test/1.html: No such file or directory.*
Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTML::HeadParser;
use Text::CSV;


my $csv1 = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } ) or die Text::CSV->error_diag();
$csv1->eol ("\n");

my $dfile = 'all_tags.csv';
open my $fh1, ">:encoding(utf8)", "$dfile" or die "Error opening $dfile: $!";


my $dir = 'Test';
find (\&HTML_Files, $dir);
print "directory is";
print $dir;
close $fh1 or die "Error closing $dfile: $!";
exit;

sub HTML_Files {
   Parse_HTML_Header($File::Find::name) if /\.html?$/;
}


sub Parse_HTML_Header {

   my $ifile = shift;
   open(my $fh0, '<', $ifile) or die "Error opening $ifile: $!\n";
   my $text = '';
   {
      $/ = undef;
      $text = <$fh0>;
   }
   close $fh0;

   my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
   my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new($h);
   $p->parse($text);


   for ($h->header_field_names) {
      my @values = split ',', $h->header($_);
      if (/keywords/i) {
         $csv1->print ($fh1, \@values);
      } elsif (/description/i) {
         $csv1->print ($fh1, \@values);
      } elsif (/title/i) {
         $csv1->print ($fh1, \@values);

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths?

Answer (score 1):

It's because [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) is doing a `chdir` as it runs. You should pass `$_` instead of `$File::Find::name`. Or set `no_chdir`:

> no_chdir
>
> Does not chdir() to each directory as it recurses. The wanted() function will need to be aware of this, of course. In this case, $_ will be the same as $File::Find::name .

Because you are specifying a relative path, `$File::Find::name` is also a relative path. You can avoid this by specifying a full path to `find` as well. (e.g. `/full/path/to/dir`)

Comment: Thanks Sobrique.  I tried your suggestion and still get the same error.  Replacing the "Test" with "." and putting the *.html file right in the directory that I'm running the script from doesn't throw and error but also creates a 0 byte parse results file.

Comment: Here's the html I'm hoping to parse: <head><title>
 Sales Jobs in Honolulu, HI on CareerBuilder.com
</title>.  Seems simple enough but I'm failing miserably.

Comment: The callback to `find()` is calling another subroutine, which is doing the `shift`. That part looks OK to me.

Comment: OK, I did a little more work and find that if I remove the Test directory I throw a "Can't stat Test: No such file or directory" which I get.  If I put the directory back in without and *.html file in the script runs but all_tags.csv contains no data.  I get that too.  Putting my 2.html file in the directory Test throws the error "Error opening Test/2.html: No such file or directory". It calls the file name out but says it can't see it?  That I don't get.  I'll continue to try and trouble shoot.  Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: OK - similar problem. `find` is doing `chdir` - try either `   Parse_HTML_Header($_)` or setting no_chdir

Comment: @Sobrique Ah, yes, I believe that's it.

Comment: So I get the explanation and I think the thing I'd like to do is set no_chdir.  I've never done that.  Looks like no_chdir => 0.  But I'm not sure where to insert that.  Thanks.

Comment: I think I see it.  I'll try it here: find (\&HTML_Files, no_chdir => 0, $dir);

Comment: OK, that's wrong, trying this find ({wanted =>\&HTML_Files, no_chdir => 1}, $dir);

Comment: OK that runs but still a 0 byte file where I'm expecting data.

Comment: OK, got it to work.  Maybe a UTF encoding thing.  Made a super simple dummy file with head><title>Test</title></head> and it correctly pulled the word Test.